# Is a query with UNIX_TIMESTAMP using indexes in mysql?

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, functions

If I use

```
.. WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`some_timestamp`)>NOW()
```

in a SELECT, does this query still make use on an index, set on `some_timestamp` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Up to now, the optimizer in all MySQL versions cannot use an index for such a condition. It is not [**sargable**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

If you want it to be able to use indexes, you'll have to use a function to rewrite/reverse your condition so no function is applied on the column:

```
WHERE some_timestamp > ReverseFunctionOf_UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW() )
```

What to use, depends on the column `some_timestamp` datatype.

---

If it is a `TIMESTAMP`, you can simply use

```
WHERE some_timestamp> NOW()
```

---

If `some_timestamp` is an `INT` that stores Unix timestamps (seconds since `'1970-01-01 00:00:00'`), I think you had the correct function but in the wrong place. You should use:

```
WHERE some_timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW() )
```

or the equivalent:

```
WHERE some_timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

---

Check MySQL documentation: **[`DATE` and `TIME` functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)**

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME()` does the reverse of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: Yes. But what is best to use, depends on the column datatype. If it is a `TIMESTAMP`, you can simply use `column > NOW()`

Comment: If it is an `INT` that stores Unix timestamps (seconds since `'1970-01-01 00:00:00'`), you should use `column > UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW() )`

Comment: thanks, the **sargable** issue was new to me. i think i will have a lot of fun with that new knowledge ;)

Comment: @rubo77: Bear in mind that the Wikipedia article is mostly correct but not 100% accurate. The examples of non-surgable conditions are very good (and the rewrites). The parts though that say *"left part of a sql condition"*, you can safely ignore.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ it seems that the Wikipedia article got censored `Wikipedia does not have an article with this exact name. Please search for Sargable in Wikipedia to check for alternative titles or spellings`

Comment: @Ivanov right, thnx. Seems like the page was removed from Wikipedia at October 2017 (reason: *"Notability of term called into question."*): [Sargable: Revision history](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sargable&action=history) The page content can still be viewed in the Internet Archive: [web.archive.org : Wikipedia: Sargable](https://web.archive.org/web/20170222053424/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)